How Can I Display Answers With Metadata in a Q&A Chatbot Using Langchain?
I'm trying to retrieve metadata from the answers, but it's returning empty values. Additionally, I need to implement a mechanism to upload multiple documents (PDF, DOCX, or TXT). How can I achieve this effectively?
My Code
all_text = " "

# Process each uploaded file
for file_name, file_content in uploaded_files.items():
    if file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
        # Process PDF file
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(io.BytesIO(file_content))
        text = ""
        for page in pdf_reader.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()
    elif file_name.endswith('.txt'):
        # Process TXT file
        text = file_content.decode("utf-8")
    elif file_name.endswith('.docx'):
        # Process DOCX file
        text = docx2txt.process(io.BytesIO(file_content))
    else:
        # Unsupported file type
        print(f"Unsupported file type: {file_name}")
        continue

    # Append text to all_text
    all_text += text
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    # Set a really small chunk size, just to show.
    chunk_size=500,
    chunk_overlap=50,
    length_function=len,
    is_separator_regex=False,
)
chunks = text_splitter.split_text(all_text)
embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model = "models/embedding-001", google_api_key=apikey)
vector_store = FAISS.from_texts(chunks, embedding=embeddings)

query = "what are Types of Reflection"
docs = vector_store.similarity_search(query,k=2)
docs

query = "what are Types of Reflection"
docs = vector_store.similarity_search(query,k=2)
docs

